# Publish asp.net application to godaddy web server

Tags: asp.net, deploying

I have a completed web form application (with 3 SQL server databases tied to it) that I created with visual studio and I want to upload it to my godaddy server.  My application needs to go to a specific folder in my server so I would prefer to export it to my desktop and manually drag the files to the file manager of goDaddy, as opposed to using the built-in publishing ftp tool on visual studio.

The problem is that after i publish to my local drive, I get a bunch of .aspx files that I can't open with chrome, let alone on my server.  Is there some sort of post-processing I need to do to get my .aspx files to an html readable format?

Any clarification would be great, I'm very confused from what I could gather online.  I tried installing IIS, using goDaddy profiles, and publishing directly but I'm still having trouble.

Thank you,

Dan

Comment: Godaddy provide FTP, from where you can put your files in wwwroot folder. Simple.

Comment: this works when you upload standard html files but when you upload aspx files, it doesnt work, thats why its really confusing.  I'm wondering if using the visual studio publishing method is the only way to achieve an aspx website.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to deploy using the 'FTP' Publish Method.

In order to complete this you need the user name and password from the GoDaddy Hosting Details page where under FTP Users. If you don't have any users listed, set an FTP User up and use that username and password in your Visual Studio Publish Profile. The Server should be set to "ftp://yoursite.com" where "yoursite.com" is the domain name for your website.

Comment: is there a way to do this manually by any chance? I like uploading the files to the server myself instead of using the publishing tool

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my issue by resorting to another server: somee.com.  Godaddy was a nightmare and I gave up after 1 week of troubleshooting.  The hosting procedure is very simple now:

1)publish application on visual studio
2)manually script the databases
3)update the connection string

works every time.